# Height difference between brake and gas pedals

Tags: pedals, brake-pedal

Previous car - Chevy Cruze 2013 LT, brake pedal higher than gas pedal (closer to the body) by 3-4 cm.

New car - Chevy Cruze Premier RS 2017, brake pedal higher than gas pedal by about 6.5 cm.

This is the first time I ever became aware of the difference in height between the two pedals because it requires an exaggerated leg movement to go from the gas to the brake pedal.

This makes it tiring on the leg during city driving and I believe more dangerous because it increases the reaction time in case of a sudden braking situation.

I called the dealer to ask about this and they said it is by design and they can't do anything about it. I even had an online chat with a GM guy who said check with the dealer - he wasn't impressed by the increased danger and potential liability on GMs part if this is proven to be faulty design.

I alleviated the issue by adding a few layers of padding on top of the gas pedal, but I'm wondering if there is a specific reason for this higher difference. I personally can't think of any advantage, just negatives. Is it maybe specific to sportier cars? And if so, why?

Comment: Interesting. I think it may just be one of those aspects of design which was over-looked. One suggestion: I was able to teach myself to use both feet for the brake and gas pedal (L food on brake, R foot on gas). This is frowned on my most people, but it is possible to learn. I would keep my L foot on the left side of the brake pedal. When I need to come to a stop, I'd put both feet on the brake pedal. I'd try to only use my L foot, but allow my R foot to take over if my L foot was not pressing the pedal hard enough. Over time, my L foot gained enough control to operate the brake on its own.

Comment: I'm curious why you made this change, what's the advantage of braking with the left foot?

Comment: Well I had learned to drive with a manual car, so I am used to using both my feet. When I began driving an automatic car recently, I started using both feet because I thought it would be fun. In theory, it is safer to use both feet, because you are able to press the brake pedal quicker compared to moving your R foot from the gas to the brake. But it took a few weeks to get used to. Towards the begining, I would press the brake pedal too hard with my L foot, similar to how a new driver often brakes too hard.

Comment: The design idea is that you can rest your heel on the floor while using the gas pedal, but for the brake your heel is off the floor so you can use the full force of your leg muscles. Having driven (manual) cars designed like that for 50 years, I guess I'm just used to it by now. The clutch pedal is the same height as the brake, for the same reason - you are not supposed to leave your left foot resting on it all the time.

Comment: I understand why there needs to be a difference between brake and gas pedals, but why so much more than the average car (at least that I'm familiar with).

Comment: @Ady left foot braking is not a “new” thing - it has been around a while both for automatic & manual...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-foot_braking